# Difference between Isolated COM and Registration free DLL for COM?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, com

I have read up on the MSDN that there is activation for registration free DLL and Isolated COM but I couldnt find what the difference is?

I am currently using a manifest file depicited in the walkthrough for DLL registration free. Can anyone enlighten me regarding to the difference? I prefer not to have a xxx.manifest at the final destination folder for the installation but yet to keep the registration free of the DLL.

Thank you

Comment: It is the same thing.  A manifest is required.

Comment: I had thought that "isolated COM' and "registration free COM" were the same thing as far as COM is concerned.  However, an isolated application might need more than just registration free COM to be considered isolated?

Answer (score 3):

They're the same thing.

"Isolated COM" is what Visual Studio guys call it [[1]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173402.aspx), "Registration-free COM" or "Registration-free Activation" is what .NET guys call it [[2]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1h056h.aspx) [[3]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) [[4]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973915.aspx).

The supporting technology is "Isolated Applications" [[5]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375190.aspx).  However, to really understand the COM side of it, I highly recommend reading [[3]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) and [[4]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973915.aspx) (walkthroughs).